# Object not found in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add the values of the variable "Chatbot" as my labels for the x-axis. It has worked before, but now I get an error that the object "Chatbot" is not found.

```
BOTTRP %>%
  ggplot(aes(Chatbot, Mean,
             colour = Scale))+
  geom_point(size = 2)+
  labs(y = "Mean of chatbot evaluation", size=3)+
  theme_gray()+
  expand_limits(x=1:10, y=1:5)+
  scale_x_continuous(labels=as.character(Chatbot), breaks=Chatbot)
```

The data frame I am using is "BOTTRP" and looks like this:

```
   Chatbot    Mean   Scale
1        1 2.96388  German
2        1 2.99666 English
3        2 3.46944  German
4        2 3.93650 English
5        3 3.02500  German
6        3 3.58095 English
7        4 4.06388  German
8        4 4.07619 English
9        5 2.90555  German
10       5 3.33968 English
11       6 3.83055  German
12       6 3.96190 English
13       7 3.30555  German
14       7 3.48666 English
15       8 3.18888  German
16       8 3.47301 English
17       9 3.29166  German
18       9 3.78730 English
19      10 3.17500  German
20      10 3.60317 English
```

I used the same code to produce what I wanted, but now it does not work anymore (also not on the other data frame.

The error message I get is:

```
Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'Chatbot' not found
```

What I would like to end up with is something that looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sA56.png)

What have I done that it does not work anymore?

Comment: your ggplot call is missing the DATA argument. Was it passed with a pipe? If not, you should include the argument `data=BOTTRP` in the ggplot call. Maybe you should show us `head(BOTTRP)`, and either `str(BOTTRP)`or `names(BOTTRP)`

Comment: @GuedesBF they actually did have it in their code, but the first line of code got cut because it wasn't on a new line after the backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the `scale_x_continuous`, since (1) it's discrete, so (2) we can `factor` the data.

```r
ggplot(BOTTRP, aes(factor(Chatbot), Mean, colour = Scale))+
  geom_point(size = 2)+
  labs(y = "Mean of chatbot evaluation", size=3)+
  theme_gray()+
  expand_limits(x=1:10, y=1:5)
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your quick response.

Unfortunately, when I try to run the command without the argument it only shows me four labels on the x-axis (2.5, 5, 7.5, 10). That's the reason why I was trying the argument in the first place.

Comment: Oh my bad, I did not get the factor part. I'll try this.